# Error Building NumPy wheel in Termux due to deprecation of `numpy.distutils`

Tags: python, numpy, termux, installation-package

When I tried to build NumPy library v-1.25.2 building the wheels failed and give me this error message

```
termux
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1                                           
╰─> [269 lines of output]
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:69: DeprecationWarning:

      `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
      of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
      Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
      It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python 
      versions.
      For more details, see:
        https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html


      import numpy.distutils.command.sdist
      Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
      Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
      fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
      Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
      Cythonizing sources
      INFO: blas_opt_info:
      INFO: blas_armpl_info:
      INFO: customize UnixCCompiler
      INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: blas_mkl_info:
      INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: blas_ssl2_info:
      INFO:   libraries fjlapackexsve not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: blis_info:
      INFO:   libraries blis not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: openblas_info:
      INFO:   libraries openblas not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: accelerate_info:
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      INFO:   libraries tatlas not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      INFO:   libraries satlas not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_blas_threads_info:
      INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_blas_info:
      INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-wzf9b3sn/numpy_278dc6028c964b47bf799e8f69f085a1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:2154: UserWarning:
          Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
          Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
          A better performance should be easily gained by switching
          Blas library.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      INFO: blas_info:
      INFO:   libraries blas not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-wzf9b3sn/numpy_278dc6028c964b47bf799e8f69f085a1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:2154: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      INFO: blas_src_info:
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-wzf9b3sn/numpy_278dc6028c964b47bf799e8f69f085a1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:2154: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
      INFO: lapack_opt_info:
      INFO: lapack_armpl_info:
      INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: lapack_mkl_info:
      INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: lapack_ssl2_info:
      INFO:   libraries fjlapackexsve not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: openblas_lapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries openblas not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: openblas_clapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: flame_info:
      INFO:   libraries flame not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_3_10_info:
      INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_threads_info:
      INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_info:
      INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: lapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries lapack not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-wzf9b3sn/numpy_278dc6028c964b47bf799e8f69f085a1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1972: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      INFO: lapack_src_info:
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-wzf9b3sn/numpy_278dc6028c964b47bf799e8f69f085a1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1972: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
      INFO:   FOUND:
      INFO:     language = c
      INFO:
      Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running config_cc
      INFO: unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      INFO: unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      INFO: build_src
      INFO: building py_modules sources
      creating build
      creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.11
      creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.11/numpy
      creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.11/numpy/distutils
      INFO: building library "npymath" sources
      WARN: Could not locate executable armflang
      WARN: Could not locate executable gfortran
      WARN: Could not locate executable f95
      WARN: Could not locate executable ifort
      WARN: Could not locate executable ifc
      WARN: Could not locate executable lf95
      WARN: Could not locate executable pgfortran
      WARN: Could not locate executable nvfortran
      WARN: Could not locate executable f90
      WARN: Could not locate executable f77
      WARN: Could not locate executable fort
      WARN: Could not locate executable efort
      WARN: Could not locate executable efc
      WARN: Could not locate executable g77
      WARN: Could not locate executable g95
      WARN: Could not locate executable pathf95
      WARN: Could not locate executable nagfor
      WARN: Could not locate executable frt
      WARN: dont know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-9dabp4ja/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 230, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-9dabp4ja/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-9dabp4ja/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 268, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-9dabp4ja/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 567, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "setup.py", line 559, in setup_package
          setup(**metadata)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-wzf9b3sn/numpy_278dc6028c964b47bf799e8f69f085a1/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
          return old_setup(**new_attr)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-9dabp4ja/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-9dabp4ja/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 324, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-wzf9b3sn/numpy_278dc6028c964b47bf799e8f69f085a1/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 62, in run
          old_build.run(self)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-wzf9b3sn/numpy_278dc6028c964b47bf799e8f69f085a1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 144, in run
          self.build_sources()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-wzf9b3sn/numpy_278dc6028c964b47bf799e8f69f085a1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 155, in build_sources
          self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-wzf9b3sn/numpy_278dc6028c964b47bf799e8f69f085a1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 288, in build_library_sources
          sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-wzf9b3sn/numpy_278dc6028c964b47bf799e8f69f085a1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
          source = func(extension, build_dir)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-wzf9b3sn/numpy_278dc6028c964b47bf799e8f69f085a1/numpy/core/setup.py", line 672, in get_mathlib_info
          mlibs = check_mathlib(config_cmd)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-wzf9b3sn/numpy_278dc6028c964b47bf799e8f69f085a1/numpy/core/setup.py", line 399, in check_mathlib
          raise RuntimeError(
      RuntimeError: math library missing; rerun setup.py after setting the MATHLIB env variable
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried  to install the packages it refers to in the error message and set the variables but the error persists.
My python version: 3.11.4

Answer (score 0):

Try following code,

```
pkg i python-numpy
```

It worked for me.